# Conflicts when using a visual studio modelling project with svn

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, uml

My project team is currently working on a modelling project for a mid-sized piece of software with Visual Studio 2010. We are using AnkhSVN for source control. 
We are not editing files concurrently, we only edit different files in the same project.

Sadly, after each commit, there are a lot of conflicts in a file with the ending **.uml**, located in a folder with the name **ModelDefinition**. This file seems to be changed whenever any diagramm in the whole solution is changed.

If we put this file on the SVN ignore list, so we can work on the modelling project concurrently, all files in the subversion are displayed as blank files.

Is there a way aroud this dilemma, so we can edit our modelling project simultaneously by using SVN?

Comment: Why don't you write your classes as normal code and generate the UML automatically? This way has proven to work a lot better than the reverse. All that is left for you to do at the end is some finishing touches (dragging classes around, adding associations and such). A big advantage is that you can also generate the class documentation automatically if you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSDN has [instructions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd574364) for sharing modeling projects. Basically, you have to organize the modelling elements into packages in the UML Model Explorer. If you put the elements into different packages, they will also be put in different .uml files.

The quickest way I've found to reorganize an existing diagram is to create a new package in the Model Explorer, set the Linked Package property of the diagram you want to move to the new package, select everything in the diagram, copy it, delete it, and paste it again.

Comment: The explanation sounds adventurous: "always perform Check In and Get Latest Version operations on the complete modeling project, never on individual files.", "Always perform a Get operation immediately before you check in the modeling project.", "Always close all diagrams before you perform a Get operation.". Sounds like the UML editor is just not designed to work well with source control. Otherwise, why would there be *one* global file that is affected by *all* changes?

Comment: "Adventurous" is kind of an understatement. The article essentially tells you that it's impossible for two users to work on the same package!

Comment: Yeah, but at least there's an article that tells you how you can't do it!

Comment: We used this solution togehter with TFS - Worked like a charm since TFS managed to solve almost all conflicts. Sadly, TortoiseSVN was not capable of merging the XML files of the modelling project correctly. 

Thank you.